# why do I get this error "make: *** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop."

Tags: 20.04, git, make

I am doing an install of git on Ubuntu 20.04, according to [this tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git).  I executed from "**Install Git on Linux**", the *Debian/Ubuntu* parts. And then I get the errors:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

at point 3 under "**Build Git from source on Linux**". I am new to Linux, but it seems as though `make` is automatically installed. When I run:

```
apt list --installed
```

it is listed:

```
make/focal,now 4.2.1-1.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Can you help on how to take this forward or approach learning about the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu) Simply use `sudo apt install git`. Do not invent bicycles with square wheels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to install software in Ubuntu. You can install software using APT, Snap, Flatpak, AppImage, installing from source, etc.

As far as what I can understand, you are trying to install `git` from source.

I would personally not suggest new Ubuntu/Linux users to install software from source as it is a bit complex than compared to other methods.

In [the article which you have mentioned](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git), following these steps will install `git` using APT:

> **Debian / Ubuntu (apt-get)**
>
> Git packages are available via [apt](https://wiki.debian.org/Apt):
>
> 1. From your shell, install Git using apt-get:
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo apt-get update
>    ```
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo apt-get install git
>    ```
> 2. Verify the installation was successful by typing
>    `git --version`:
>
>    ```
>    $ git --version
>    ```
>
>    ```
>    git version 2.9.2
>    ```
> 3. Configure your Git username and email using the following commands, replacing Emma's name with your own. These details will be associated with any commits that you create:
>
>    ```
>    $ git config --global user.name "Emma Paris"
>    ```
>
>    ```
>    $ git config --global user.email "eparis@atlassian.com"
>    ```

To know more about installing software in Ubuntu, read these:

- https://medium.com/geekculture/5-different-ways-to-install-software-on-ubuntu-linux-14ae6b95d1d2
- [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/25961) (I suggest you research a bit about [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall).)